# At the end of Webview, an underline is display. how to remove the underline in IOS 8 beta?

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, ios8, xcode6

I am using webview (in Xcode 6 beta) and in web view I put htmlContents.
  And after end of the web view an underline is shown in **iPhone 5 (IOS 8)**. 
How to remove this underline in **IOS 8 beta**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following line of code in your code :

```
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 webView.opaque = FALSE;
```